# return json data from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void contacters()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        List<object> obj = new List<object>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from authors", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        for(int i=0; i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)

        {
            obj.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
            obj.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
            obj.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = ser.Serialize(obj);
        Context.Response.Write("{"+'"'+"info"+'"'+";"+json+"}");
    }
```

This Is my Web service

And My JS File

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post("WebService2.asmx/contacters")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response.data.info;
        console.log(response.data.info);
    });
});
```

My Code On ASPX `testjson.aspx`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.AuthorId }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Fname }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.Lname }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testjavascript.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

webservice is displaying data when i debug webservice,

But the problem is when i run the page `testjson.aspx` data is not displaying

> Can anybody help me out on this

web service is running fine, I think there may be a

> problem in my JS file

Comment: Try debuggin the JS function. Check the content of "response.data.info;".

Comment: It looks like you are sending invalid JSON. Use **:** instead of **;**

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov in js or in webservice?

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh In WebService. Make it  `Context.Response.Write("{"+'"'+"info"+'"'+":"+json+"}");`

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov nothing happend, And I think the problem is not with webservice, the problem is with javascript fil or with aspx page

Comment: Where are you using the class `contact`?

Comment: What is `x.AuthorId` ? Why did you write it

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov it is a column name

Comment: @RichaGarg I removed that

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov column name in sql table

Comment: Are you getting the json in correct format?

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh  the column name `AuthorId` is not serialized into  json

Comment: @RichaGarg when i debug web service i am getting everything fine

`{"info":[13,"one nizam","siddiqui",15,"three","siddiquibfgg",30,"fowzan","Ansari",34,"nizam siddiqui","nizam siddiqui"]}` this is what i get

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh where is `AuthorId` in your json?

Comment: This is not in correct format

Comment: I knw I did many mistakes, this is my first webservice with json and javascript guys please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public void contacters()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    List<ContactModel> obj = new List<ContactModel>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from authors", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        obj.Add(new ContactModel
                    {
                    AuthorId = (int) ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0],
                    Fname = (string) ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1],
                    Lname = (string) ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]
                    });
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var returnModel = new { info = obj };
    var json = ser.Serialize(returnModel);
    Context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Comment: still not getting anything

Comment: Use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to test the response

Comment: I am using this extension

Answer (score 1):

you response is serialized so you need to parse in your script, try this

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

And also you can return web service as string type with static method like below code.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string contacters()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    List<object> obj = new List<object>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from authors", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    for(int i=0; i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)

    {
        obj.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]);
        obj.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
        obj.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);
    }enter code here
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = ser.Serialize(obj);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(data);` where i need to pass this?

Comment: $scope.names = response.data.info;

Comment: before that you have to pars Json data

Comment: This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace.

Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public.

Comment: You need to check your json response format.seem issue with json format

Comment: I was Using framework 4.6 Now when i changed it to 4.0 its working